# Unable to install jenkins on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, digital-ocean, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to install jenkins on digitalOcean ubuntu 22.04, but its not working.

i have tried following versions:

```
wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.4_all.deb

wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.3_all.deb

wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.2_all.deb

wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.1_all.deb

wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.346.3_all.deb

wget https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.346.2_all.deb
```

but i am getting below error for all the version

```
--2022-08-29 14:55:34--  https://pkg.jenkins.io/debian-stable/binary/jenkins_2.332.4_all.deb
Resolving pkg.jenkins.io (pkg.jenkins.io)... 151.101.158.133, 2a04:4e42:25::645
Connecting to pkg.jenkins.io (pkg.jenkins.io)|151.101.158.133|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.4_all.deb [following]
--2022-08-29 14:55:35--  https://mirrors.jenkins.io/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.4_all.deb
Resolving mirrors.jenkins.io (mirrors.jenkins.io)... 52.167.253.43
Connecting to mirrors.jenkins.io (mirrors.jenkins.io)|52.167.253.43|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.4_all.deb [following]
--2022-08-29 14:55:37--  https://mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/jenkins/debian-stable/jenkins_2.332.4_all.deb
Resolving mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn (mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn)... 101.6.15.130, 2402:f000:1:400::2
Connecting to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn (mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn)|101.6.15.130|:443... failed: Connection timed out.
Connecting to mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn (mirrors.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn)|2402:f000:1:400::2|:443... failed: Network is unreachable.
```

Please let me know if more details needed, i am new to jenkins installation on ubuntu.

Comment: have you installed JDK ? Can you try to follow this and let me know which step your installation fails ? https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-jenkins-on-ubuntu-22-04

Comment: yes i have install open jdk 11, i have followed above link for installation. Everything work good until i try to run sudo apt install jenkins.

Comment: Have u tried following some other documentation ?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and tried to follow the steps given in above digital ocean link but no luck.

Then managed to fix the issue by correcting the dpkg package issue and installing correct java and JRE tools to meet the Jenkins LTS (since Jenkins 2.357 and LTS 2.361.1)

First of all reboot Ubuntu

```
reboot
```

Secondly, Install Open JDK 17

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jdk
sudo apt install openjdk-17-jre
```

After successfully installation of JDK 17, one last time **reboot** and run the following commands to re-install Jenkins

```
sudo apt-get purge jenkins
apt-get install jenkins
```

Now check the status `sudo systemctl status jenkins.service` and it should be running automatically and if not then you can explicitly start it by typing `sudo systemctl start jenkins`

Comment: I only had to install the JDK before installing Jenkins (I need the JDK anyway).